# Why is the data in my node singleton not what I placed there?

Tags: node.js, singleton

In node, I need to pass an object from one file to another, so am attempting to use a singleton with a setter and a getter. I'm sure I've done this successfully using this same method, but when I go the get the object, it's not what it should be.

Here's the code in its entirety:

```
module.exports.setLocals = (ref, data) => {
  let locals = {
    previousEntries: data.previousEntries ? data.previousEntries : {},
    errors: {},
    current: {},
    ref: ref
  };
  console.log(locals);
  return;
};

module.exports.getLocals = () => {
  console.log(locals);
  return locals;
};
```

I call setLocals thusly:

```
locals.setLocals(ref, req.reqId);
```

and the locals object  gets set to { previousEntries: {}, errors: {}, current: {}, ref: '2aa8d390' }, which is what I'm expecting.

However when I call getLocals, doing console.log on locals gives me garbage.

Can someone give me a pointer or two? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an issue with scoping. The `locals` in `setLocals` is not the same as the one in `getLocals` (due to `let`).

If you initiate `locals` outside both methods scops you will be able to share it.

```
const locals = {
  ... default values.
};

module.exports.setLocals = (ref, data) => {
  locals = {  // <---- remove let
    previousEntries: data.previousEntries ? data.previousEntries : {},
    errors: {},
    current: {},
    ref: ref
  }
  console.log(locals);
  return;
};

module.exports.getLocals = () => {
  console.log(locals);
  return locals;
};
```